# Hide the status bar on an iPhone

Tags: display, iphone

Is it possible to hide the status bar (battery indicator, time, etc.) on an iPhone? I can't find any indication of this in settings but I can't figure out if it's just not possible or if I'm looking in the wrong place. I went into Settings and looked in General and Display.

When I search for this I keep getting StackOverflow answers about hiding (or showing) the status bar programmatically. I want to know if there's a way to do this on the device itself.

The phone I'm trying to do this on is an iPhone 5, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible to hide it on an unjailbroken iPhone.

Comment: Is there any official documentation on this I should have been able to find or is it that I didn't find anything because the option doesn't exist?

Comment: The option does not exist in the UI. Apps can hide the status bar, however, if designed to.

Answer (score 0):

Hold your power button down until the "slide to power off" option appears. Slide it halfway and keep your finger there. Wait till you get a notification and click it without lifting your finger that's holding the slide to power off switch halfway. And it's gone.